# HTTP PUT Request not allowed

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I am trying to add some data to a database using Google Apps Script HTTP PUT Request.

Here is the JSON format of my database:

[image]

What I need to do is to add another Object, `7: Object` with name "New Rule" to the `rules` array from "Adobe Analytics".

I have some code but it returns me the following error:

> Error: Request failed for https://example.com returned code 405. Truncated server response: HTTP method not allowed, supported methods: GET, POST (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

```
  var restHeaders = {    
    'Key': "...",
    'Authorization':'Bearer ...',
  }
  var request = {
    "name": "Adobe Analytics",
    "id": 3,
    "rules":[
      {
        "name": "New Rule",
        "tags": [
          {
            "tagId": 1,
            "condition": false,
          },
          {
            "tagId": 1,
            "condition": false,
          }
        ],
        "ruleSetId": 3,
      }
    ]
  }
  var opt = {
    'method': 'put',
    'headers': restHeaders,
    'contentType' : 'application/json',
    'payload': JSON.stringify(request)
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get says :
"**supported methods: GET, POST**" while your parameter object

```
var opt = {
    'method': 'put',
```

is using '**PUT**' as an HTTP method.
Following the error , the Server is not configured for PUT requests but only for GET and POST.

Comment: And is there another way that allows me to use the `PUT` Request?

Comment: If the Server is configured to allow only GET and POST requests/methods then there is no way you could use POST against him.

You will either have to configure the Server to accept PUT method/requests or use a GET/POST on your side.

If you have the flexibility to use POST or GET , then i dont see any reason why you shouldn't. The server will accept your request and your work will be done.

Comment: @PavelValeriu why do you think PUT is to be accepted? What are the API docs suggesting?

Comment: @Jonathon sorry for my late response...in the google apps script docs it says that the PUT method is supported: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app. I need to use this method to update the JSON object

Comment: It is for the server returning the 405 to support PUT regardless of Apps Script

Comment: i.e. Where is your database?